# estoy trabajando con una api pero no me muestra la informacion en la vista

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

este es la api en formato `json` que se encuentra en internet

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "per_page": 6,
  "total": 12,
  "total_pages": 2,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "email": "george.bluth@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "George",
      "last_name": "Bluth",
      "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "email": "janet.weaver@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "Janet",
      "last_name": "Weaver",
      "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/2-image.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "email": "emma.wong@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "Emma",
      "last_name": "Wong",
      "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/3-image.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "email": "eve.holt@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "Eve",
      "last_name": "Holt",
      "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/4-image.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "email": "charles.morris@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "Charles",
      "last_name": "Morris",
      "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/5-image.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "email": "tracey.ramos@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "Tracey",
      "last_name": "Ramos",
      "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/6-image.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "support": {
    "url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading",
    "text": "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"
  }
}
```

este es mi controlador

```
    string baseurl = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1";
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {        
        List<Usuarios> Empinfo = new List<Usuarios>();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            //llena todas las personas usando el httpclient
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("api/users/");
            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //si res es true entra y asigna los datos
                var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                //Deserializar el api y almacena los datos
                Empinfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Usuarios>>(EmpResponse);
            }
        }
        return View(Empinfo);
    }
```

Comment: 3 cosas: 1. Bienvenido/a, asegúrate de leer el recorrido, te ayudará entender de mejor manera el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtienes tu primera medalla. 2. Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 3.¿Sabes cómo funcionan los `using`?

Comment: y si estas recibiendo los datos en `Empinfo` o es nullo?, si es null es porque no estas Deserializando bien el json

Answer (score 0):

Parece que no estás esperando a recibir la respuesta de la petición y regresas Empinfo antes de asignarle un valor.

Intenta poniendo el return dentro del if y agrega un else en caso de que la petición no se complete:

```
string baseurl = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1";
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{        
    List<Usuarios> Empinfo = new List<Usuarios>();
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        //llena todas las personas usando el httpclient
        HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("api/users/");
        if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //si res es true entra y asigna los datos
            var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            //Deserializar el api y almacena los datos
            Empinfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Usuarios>>(EmpResponse);
            return View(Empinfo);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: si lo agrego como dices, marca un error que es ambigua la llamada entre los metodos

Comment: En la misma línea donde regresas Empinfo? Puedes compartir el error que te marca?

Comment: marca error en return view(null) dice que ambugua la llamada entre los metodos